# sqlite3 in iphone with 50 coulmns in a table. does performance create problem?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sdk

I am using sqlit3 in my iphone application to store details of the user 
I have a table carrying of 50 columns. Now i have to insert data within the columns. can anybody suggest optimum way to do that which will not impact the performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is to try whatever comes to mind, and if it's too slow, well, try something else. What have you tried? Are you experiencing performance problems?

Comment: yes, i am doing the same. but still if in case anybody else have encountered the same scenario, their thought would be helpful. experiment is going on.. :)

Comment: please post your results when you have them, i'm curious to know the answer.  pure guess on my part, but i bet the iphone has no problem with that size table.  50 columns is pretty teensy, particularly when it comes to data inserts.  now, if you have lots and lots and lots of 50 column tables, and lots and lots and lots of data in them, then joins could get interesting...

Comment: @justin: please dont scare me. i'm newbie :) fortunately..i hv only 3 table with one carrying 50+ columns and 25+ records in that table.

Comment: finally.. i made sequence insertion... keeping the column segerated as per the screen and update as per the edit happened to that screen.. its working ..

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't store empty columns, so having 50 columns will have no impact until you start putting data into them.  After you insert data, it will start to take up space, but the additional cost will be minimal.  What performance problems are you specifically worried about?

Comment: performance in terms of data retrieval from db while transition from one view to another, like it should not see visible delay to do that and this was my concern.. thanks for reply.

Comment: SQLite is faster than you think it is.  I'd recommend trying this first, before worrying about optimizations.  Odds are, your own supporting code will be much slower than the SQLite accesses.

Comment: @Brad: reason for my worry is i'm stuck with limited time to develop and i dont want to revisit the same screen because of same reason. else i would be doing all types of permutation :) and Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0):

There's always Core Data. Seems like a snappy option, as well.